# looking for a really simple racket macro example

Tags: racket, lisp-macros

I did this:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (macro-expansion-seconds)
  (current-seconds))
```

which does this

```
> (macro-expansion-seconds)
1639244531
> (macro-expansion-seconds)
1639244532
> (macro-expansion-seconds)
1639244533
```

It replaces `(macro-expandsion-seconds)` with `(current-seconds)` at expansion time, and still evaluates that form each time.

But how do I make it evaluate `(current-seconds)` at expansion time, and then do this?

```
> (macro-expansion-seconds)
1639244533
> (macro-expansion-seconds)
1639244533
> (macro-expansion-seconds)
1639244533
```

I know in this case I could just do this

```
(define macro-expansion-seconds
  (current-seconds))
```

and this

```
> macro-expansion-seconds
1639244766
> macro-expansion-seconds
1639244766
> macro-expansion-seconds
1639244766
```

(name no longer makes sense)

but I am trying to figure out how macros work, and thought this would be an easy example that could help me figure out harder ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
#lang racket

(begin-for-syntax
  (define the-time (current-seconds)))

(define-syntax (macro-expansion-seconds stx)
  (datum->syntax stx the-time))

(macro-expansion-seconds)
(macro-expansion-seconds)
(macro-expansion-seconds)
```

Here `begin-for-syntax` tells the expander that the following expressions are to be evaluated at compile time. Thus the value of `the-time` will be a number. The macro then needs to turn the number (which is a datum) into a piece of syntax. That's the job of `datum->syntax`.

Comment: If it's OK to ask a sub-question... How can I see the expanded macro?

Comment: Actually I'll just ask a question.

Comment: subquestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322268/how-can-i-see-expanded-macros-in-racket