# How can I see expanded macros in racket?

Tags: racket, lisp-macros

I got this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70318991 about writing a simple macro that records the time at macro expansion time, and then always returns that time.

```
#lang racket

(begin-for-syntax
  (define the-time (current-seconds)))

(define-syntax (macro-expansion-seconds stx)
  (datum->syntax stx the-time))

(macro-expansion-seconds)
(macro-expansion-seconds)
(macro-expansion-seconds)
```

It works great, but now is there an easy way to see an expanded version of `(macro-expansion-seconds)` without evaluating it? (for debugging more complicated ones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
(expand #'(macro-expansion-seconds))
```

in the DrRacket repl.

It will show you the graphical representation of a syntax object - remember to click the little arrow! In Mythical Macros I have written a little syntax objects.

https://soegaard.github.io/mythical-macros/

An alternative is to use the "Macro Stepper". Click the button in upper right corner of DrRacket: the icon is a combination of consists of a `#` and a play symbol.

Comment: Sorry - the second of your two answers should have been obvious, except, I was using emacs.  Thanks a lot. And thanks - I'll read your book.  That might be what I was really looking for!